# Specifying a refiling target at the file level

Tags: org-mode

I have a question about refiling under orgmode.  For a certain file, I want a different set of refiling targets that what I have in general (specifically, only refiling within this document itself). I'm hoping there is a header setting I can use to override the refile target for a given file, but I haven't been able to track it down despite much search. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @Drew: yes, it is - see https://orgmode.org/manual/Refile-and-Copy.html#Refile-and-Copy

Comment: I feel like I'm missing some context from @NickD's comment, but his link mentions `org-refile-targets`.  While not a file-local variable, `org-refile-targets` does let you specify refile targets for specific files.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: the comment was an answer to Drew's comment (since deleted). It does not address your question unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Continued research has revealed a partial answer, setting variables at the level of the *directory*, which is sufficient for my use case and perhaps for other. The documentation entry is

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html

and useful descriptions are at

http://endlessparentheses.com/a-quick-guide-to-directory-local-variables.html

and

http://joelmccracken.github.io/entries/project-local-variables-in-projectile-with-dirlocals/